# Quel est le dernier mot?

Tags: word, language

What is the last word / Quel est le dernier mot?

```
(a) USE, FIX, QUIDS, CURT, EXIT, TUN, NORTH, EQUIP, AXIS, ?
(b) EN, VOIE, TWIST, ENFERS, HIER, ONT, HUNE, VEXE, TOGE, ?
```

These are two separate questions.

Comment: Are the questions related, or is there an ultimate answer using both last words? If not, it would be preferred if you made separate posts for them.

Comment: @Cashbee I was told to put different but closely related questions into one question so that's confusing :)

Comment: I added the [tag:language] tag due to several French words. If this is wrong you are able to [edit/undo it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/72267/edit)

Comment: "Ce qui est le dernier mot ? " is not a grammatically correct question in French. I believe my edit preserves the intention of your question, but rollback if necessary.

Comment: @Evargalo Please cancel this edit, as my prior identical attempt was rejected. Hopefully Anush will tell us why once they have accepted an answer.

Comment: @Anush apparently they are quite related. Forget I said anything then. Nice puzzle!

Comment: @xhienne I must apologise. I wanted the wording to be exactly the same as the version I was given. In hindsight, the corrected version is OK.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> From all the letters in part b) we can form the numbers from one to ten with some letters missing.
>  So we have EN VOIE TWIST ENFERS HIER ONT HUNE VEXE TOGE
>   minus ONE = VIE TWIST ENFERS HIER ONT HUNE VEXE TOGE
>   minus TWO = VIE IST ENFERS HIER NT HUNE VEXE TOGE
>   minus THREE = VIE IS ENFERS I NT HUN VEXE TOGE
>   minus FOUR = VIE IS ENES I NT HN VEXE TGE
>   minus FIVE =  IS ENES I NT HN VEXE TGE  -> missing F
>   minus SIX =  ENES I NT HN VEE TGE
>   minus SEVEN =  I NT HN EE TGE
>   minus EIGHT =   N N E TE
>   minus NINE  =    TE  -> missing I
>   minus TEN =    TE  -> missing N
>  so, I guess the missing word is FIN.

For part a)

> In a similar manner removing one by one the French words for the numbers 1-10 we can find that we are missing the letters ned, but I guess the word in question is END, just so that it matches the French one.
>
>  USE FIX QUIDS CURT EXIT TUN NORTH EQUIP AXIS
>  minus UN = SE FIX QUIDS CURT EXIT TU NORTH EQUIP AXIS
>  minus DEUX = S FI QIS CURT EXIT TU NORTH EQUIP AXIS
>  minus TROIS = F QIS CU EXIT TU NRTH EQUIP AXIS
>  minus QUATRE = F IS C XI TU NTH EQUIP XIS
>  minus CINQ = F S XI TU TH EUIP XIS
>  minus SIX = F TU TH EUIP XIS
>  minus SEPT = F U TH UI XI
>  minus HUIT = F U XI
>  minus NEUF = XI -> missing NE
>  minus DIX -> missing D
> So the missing word is END

Comment: Very nicely done! How did you do it so quickly?

Comment: @Anush I counted the words and somehow they looked to me like one, two, three.

Comment: @rhsquared every word has the same number of letters as the corresponging word for a number.

Comment: @svavil and this well. I don't know French. I googled it. Initially, when I saw the second line, it looked like un, etc.